# Accessing JSON object by generated string in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am creating a controller in Angular for which I get the url parts and some parameters with `$statePrams`.

I call the `$http` service to get data back from a json file. After getting the data back, I assign the specified object element's content -which specification is generated from `$stateParams`- to a `$scope` variable which I can process in my view to generate some kind of unordered list elements.

My problem is when I generate for example the path as `result['data']['datas']['timeline']` , then it won't work, and give me `ngRepeat:dupe` error.

However there are no duplicates at all. If I just type it in manually like `$scope.naviData = result['data']['datas']['timeline'];` , it will generate the object, give me all the needed data and draw the `li` elements in the view.

How could I solve this problem since I do not know how to do this dynamic object element access otherwise. Here are two images:

**First one is with manual writing**
[image: first]

**Second one is with dynamically generated variable**
[image: second]
The first `console.info` in both case are the state params I generate the path from. Also here are the codes doing the magic part for me.

```js
angular.module('MPWeb.datas', [])
  .controller('DataDetailsCtrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, $http) {
    $scope.params = $stateParams;
    // set datas for dynamic object handling
    var base = 'data.datas';
    var category = ($scope.params.categoryId) ? $scope.params.categoryId : '';
    var article = ($scope.params.articleId) ? $scope.params.articleId : '';
    var stateConfig = (article) ? {
      params: {
        prefix: base,
        categoryId: category,
        articleId: article
      }
    } : {
      params: {
        prefix: base,
        categoryId: category
      }
    };
    console.info(stateConfig.params); // this is the first console entry on the screenshots
    // with this function I get back a standard joined string
    var objToString = function(obj) {
      var tabjson = [];
      for (var p in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
          tabjson.push(obj[p]);
        }
      }
      tabjson.push()
      return tabjson.join('.');
    };
    // generate sideNavigation
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: './json/mp-navigation.json'
    }).then(function successCallback(result, status, headers) {
      var temp = objToString(stateConfig.params);
      var naviTemp = (stateConfig.params.articleId) ? temp.replace(/\.[^.]+$/, "") : temp;
      naviTemp = "result['" + naviTemp + "']";
      naviTemp = naviTemp.replace(/\./g, "']['"); // dynamically generated path with bracket notation method
      //$scope.naviData = naviTemp; // if I use this, it gives me the error
      $scope.naviData = result['data']['datas']['timeline'];
      console.info(naviTemp);
    }, function errorCallback(result, status, headers) {
      console.warn(status);
    });
  });
```

Also if I use `track by $index` in my view it will just generate `li` elements from the letters of my generated path.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is you have used trackby in your ng-repeat in your template.
but the trackby accepts unique keys from the objects in array .

ex :

```
values = [{id:12,name:'king'},{id:13:name :'ram'},{id:14:name:'king'}]
```

Correct

```
<div ng-repeat="value in values  track by id">
{{value.name}} : {{value.id}}
</div>
```

Correct

```
<div ng-repeat="value in values  track by $index">
{{value.name}} : {{value.id}}
</div>
```

Wrong because name is not unique

```
<div ng-repeat="value in values  track by name">
{{value.name}} : {{value.id}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem is different I am sure. Also, in return I should get this: 
`"timeline": {
  "stormy-beginnings": "1969 - 2164",
  "to-boldly-go": "2188 - 2379",
  "golden-ages": "2380 - 2393"
}`.
Also in my view I work them with `ng-repeat="(url, name) in naviData"`, where I can use track by with url, but it still give me the errors as I mentioned in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

So after some days, I finally figured it out with a little help. For anybody who find this issue in the future, this is how to solve in the controller:

```
  $scope.params = $stateParams;
  $scope.navPrefix = $state.current.url.split('/:')[0];
  $scope.navPrefix = ($scope.params.categoryId) ? $scope.navPrefix + '/' + $scope.params.categoryId + '/' : $scope.navPrefix + '/';
  $scope.activeItem = ($scope.params.articleId) ? $scope.params.articleId : $scope.params.categoryId;
  var tempCat = $state.current.url.substr(1);
  $scope.naviCat = tempCat.split('/:')[0];
  // set datas for dynamic object handling
  var base = $scope.naviCat;
  ...
  // generate sideNavigation
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: './json/mp-navigation.json'
  }).then(function successCallback(result, status, headers) {
    var naviMain = result.data[$scope.naviCat]['main'];
    var naviTemp = result.data[stateConfig.params.prefix][stateConfig.params.categoryId];
    $scope.naviData = (stateConfig.params.categoryId == '') ? naviMain : naviTemp;
    }, function errorCallback(result, status, headers) {
      console.warn(status + ' with getting: ' + headers);
  });
```

Cheers